# Supporting newer gems on old ruby (here: Celluloid)

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8, backport, celluloid

Is it possible, by using [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) or something similar, to install and use gems that require a higher version of ruby than what is installed?

I am stuck on 1.8 and I am having troubles with the celluloid gem in relation with rspec. I thought that maybe backports would enable me to use it since most/all ruby 1.9.2+ features are then made available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forking [celluloid](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid) on github and using [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) to bring it down to 1.8 would be one possibility.

Although not a very simple one! :-)

Comment: I might actually do this, but I believe it would introduce clutter in the Gemfiles and the environment as a whole. It would have been nice if maybe Backports faked being ruby 2.1 (Or whatever target you have).

Comment: What makes you stuck on 1.8 by the way? Just curiosity! :-)

Comment: TideSDK development :)

Comment: Oh nice, didnt know that one! How do you like it?

Comment: Linke? do you mean like? I like it a lot, and it is the framework that does all the linking to ruby, which is locked to 1.8

Comment: So, I abandoned the doomed framework that used a non-standard Ruby 1.8. Now I'm using another framework and bundling my own, real, version of Ruby 2.1 :)